# Getting ID for a list item with JS

Tags: list, javascript, caml-query, spservices

I am trying to set up a simple subscription tool where users can subscribe to or unsubscribe from various distribution list. The idea is that you select a user through a people picker ('subuser'), select a list ('sublist') and click either subscribe (so you are added to the selected list) or unsubscribe (so you are deleted from the selected list). I have succeeded with the subscribe part, but got stuck at unsubscribe. I know how to delete an item from a list, but to do that I need to have an item's ID (or is there any other way?). This is the part of my code that I want to use to get the ID for the item that includes a user selected via the people picker, but itemID is undefined:

```
function removeUser()     
{    
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteurl);    
var value1 = document.getElementById('subuser').value;    
var value2 = document.querySelector('input[name="sublist"]:checked').value;    
var queryLookup = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='UserName' LookupId='TRUE' /><Value Type='Lookup'>"+ value1 +"</Value></Eq></Where>";
var itemID="";

$().SPServices({    
    operation: "GetListItems",    
    async: false,    
    listName: value2,    
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID'/></ViewFields>",    
    CAMLQuery: queryLookup,    
    completefunc: function(xData,Status) {    
        itemID = $(xData.responseXML.xml).find("z\\:row").attr("ows_ID");
        }
    });
}
```

SPServices can be replaced by any other working solution. Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the sample code using that we can get last item ID using REST API coding :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getListData() { 
        $.ajax({ 
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('ListA')/items?$select=ID,Title",
            type: "GET",
            headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose", },
            success: onQuerySucceeded, error: onQueryFailed
        });
    }
    function onQuerySucceeded(data) {
        console.log(data.d.results);
        $("#newsitems").append('<table>');
        $("#newsitems").append('<tr><td style="font-weight:bold">ID </td><td style="font-weight:bold">Title </td></tr>');
        $.each(data.d.results, function (key, value) {
        $("#newsitems").append('<tr>'); 
        $("#newsitems").append('<td>'+value.ID+ '</td>'); 
        $("#newsitems").append('<td>'+value.Title+ '</td>');                                    
        $("#newsitems").append('</tr>')                  });
        $("#newsitems").append('</table>');
    }
    function onQueryFailed() {
        alert('Sorry An Error Has Occurred!');
    }
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getListData, "sp.js")
</script>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
<div id="newsitems"></div>
```

Reference URL :

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e9964e5a-5496-44ba-a969-f239df1b2651/sharepoint-and-rest-api-trying-to-display-list-item-id?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Comment: Thanks, this way I can indeed get items' IDs from a list. However, I have two issues: 1. Is it possible to get data from a person/group column? It seems I cannot do that. In the example above we have "ID" and "Title" columns, it works, when I add another text or numeric column, it works, but it doesn't work for a person/group column.
2. I have the list of IDs, but how can I get from this the ID of the item that includes a particular value? A user gives their email through filling in a form, I need to get the ID of the item that includes this email. Can I somehow query this fetched data?

Comment: Yes, we can get person or group column as well -  there we need to use the expand attribute in the select query, please see the below example how it works : https://www.google.com/amp/s/sharepointeducation.wordpress.com/2016/07/19/getting-person-or-group-type-field-in-rest-api-sharepoint-2013/amp/

Comment: And at the end end of your REST query in the select parameter you can add "and emailid (email column) ne null (or" ") "   -  this will return the result which has email id

Comment: Getting there! One more obstacle: I can send the relevant ID to the console with the above code ('$("#newsitems").append('<td>'+value.ID+ '</td>');'), however, how can I assign this ID to a variable?

Comment: Just create a variable var myId =Value. Id    or use this example

Comment: Just create a variable var myId =Value. Id    or use this example for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++)   

            {  

                var item = data.d.results[i];  
                var MyID=item. ID

                $("#ResultDiv").append(item.Company + "\t" + item.Industry + "<br/>");  

            }